# QT : Passing QString to QThread

Tags: c++, qt

I want to pass a `QString` to a thread.Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669903/passing-qstring-to-qthread-through-signal-slot-mechanism) answer,
Here is my code:
in **MainWindow.cpp**:

```
mmthread = new mythread;
        mmthread->start();

        connect(this,SIGNAL(sendtothread(QString)),mmthread,SLOT(getfrom_main(QString)),Qt::QueuedConnection);

        emit sendtothread(mystr);
```

in **mainwindow.h**:

```
signals:
    void sendtothread(QString);
```

in **mythread.cpp**:

```
void mythread::getfrom_main(QString str)
{
    //something
}
```

in **mythread.h**:

```
public slots:
    void getfrom_main(QString);
```

But it seems `getfrom_main` is not called at all.
Where is my mistake?

**EDIT:**

I have 3 similar threads like this:

in **mythread.cpp**:

```
mythread :: mythread()
{
    moveToThread(this);
}
void mythread::run(){
    //something1
}
void mythread::getfrom_main(QString comm)
{
    comment = comm;
    emit message(comment);
}
```

in **mythread.h**:

```
    class mythread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit mythread();
    void run();
signals:
    void message (QString);
private:
       QString comment;
public slots:
    void getfrom_main(QString);
};
```

`something1` always executes in all my threads.`but not about getfrom_main`.Thanks.

Comment: Do you have in both classes the Q_OBJECT macro? Without this macro, signals and slots don't work.

Comment: @mtb Yes. both classes! I have a signal/slot for showing thread's  Qstrings comments by a QMessagebox in mainwindow and it works perfect!

Comment: Please, show an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Try starting thread after you connect signal and slot.

Comment: @Anže. Nothing changed!

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I don't like to read long texts :) ... It means I give a complete project that just has this part and this issue on it?

Comment: The code that you provide should work correct. Maybe the problem is in the part of the code that you do not provide. So, just as a suggestion, put the complete files (.h and .cpp) if there are not to big.

Comment: @mtb i will do that, but what about these answers?

Comment: @lord.h that means, that your question couldn't be answered, because you didn't do enough research by yourself and didn't provide enough information.

Comment: Btw, are there any warning messages in output?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov No there are not... Btw it seems that your are the boss! :) ... I wrote what is needed from my code clearly and also I linked similar question... anyway thank you :)

Comment: What is the class `mythread` - can you post the complete class? - for example have you base-classed QThread and overridden the `run()` at all? - The example you point to seems to be very different from your code. We need to see how you start your thread - it could be that the thread is not even running because you have not called `exec()` or something like this - but we can't tell you about it because we can't see the code - just post all of it up - its been 20 hours since people have asked for more info.... come on, shake-a-leg : )

Comment: @code_fodder .. I edited the question. thanks :)

Comment: @lord.h you need to read Qt documentation, because you misunderstood a lot: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong:

```
mythread :: mythread()
{
    moveToThread(this); // you don't need to do it
}
```

Wrong (you really don't need to inherit `QThread` in your code):

```
void mythread::run()
{
    //something1
    // after "something" you need to run an event loop:
    exec();
}
```

`exec()` will run an event loop that will process all your signals and slots.

Comment: Thanks :)... I am really beginner in Qt programming and also C++. My expert skill is not programming and now I forced to create some GUI for my purpose. So you are right about me. But look at you my friend!Excuse me but I hope other guys in `stackoverflow.com` don't be like you! You could just saying that `exec() will run an event loop . just try that!` :) ... and it worked for me without changing anything else!! I used `moveToThread(this);` after some problems and I need it :) .. so please change your answer, then i can accept that.

Comment: I'm not a mind reader. I thing that my answer is complete and good enough (because it solved your problem). It will be wrong to modify it, because someone else may have similar problems. Feel free to leave it unaccepted. I don't care about rating/reputation ;)

Comment: @lord.h ahhh... new friends : )   - it is as I suspected in my comment - you just missed calling `exec()` in `run()` - if you are not going to populate run() with any tasks then you can omit overriding this function because the default (base-class) run() function calls exec(). Without this call your thread runs, but very briefly (with no event loop) - in fact it finishes before you emit your signal and and so there is no possibility it can receive the signal.

Comment: @code_fodder ...thanks :) .Now I can understand what I wrote :)